# JS - where does this input-elemt come from (amCharts)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, amcharts

I am messing around with amCharts and trying to connect a [daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#config) to a xy-linegraph. then I found this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/5aqL5pua/
but I dont understand something.. there is this section at the bottom

```
 chart.addListener('rendered', function (event) {
    $(".amcharts-start-date-input").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "MM/DD/YYYY",
        startDate: chart.startDate,
        endDate: chart.endDate
    }).on("changeDate", function (dpEvent) {
        chart.zoom(dpEvent.date, chart.endDate);
    });
});
```

where des this `.amcharts-start-date-input`-element come from? .. there is no html-element in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the jsfiddle you'll see that some code is imported via CDN. The code targets `<div id="chartdiv"></div>` and attaches the div `<div id="amcharts-stock-div"></div>` around which it adds its own elements.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network

Comment: So you mean, the a `amcharts-start-date-input`-div gets generated progammaticly?

Comment: Exactly. If you drop that link in your browser you should get the code though it is probably minified you can use use something like https://unminify.com/ and paste the code in and search for that div to find where it is bound to the html at chartdiv